# CloudFormation: SNS creation timing issue

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I'm trying to create a CF script that spins up an EC2 instance and creates an SNS Topic that uses a service on that instance as an endpoint. My issue seems to be one of timing: the SNS topic will fail to be created because the endpoint is unresponsive... Because the instance is likely still initializing.

I have used the DependsOn attribute, but that doesn't do the trick.

I'm looking at WaitCondition, but I'm wondering where my 'signal' should be triggered: will the instance's httpd be fully initialized and externally accessible when the 'userdata' script is executed? Or is there another 'place' that I should put the signal?

Or should I be looking at CreationPolicy? From a quick reading of the docs, there seems to be a signal involved with that as well, so the above question stands for that solution as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signal should be triggered at the end of userdata script. In the userdata script, ensure that the service is up and running. You can write a loop which will poll on your service's health.

Please refer to the CreationPolicy subtopic in the [Sample template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html) link. More information on [CreationPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html)

Now your SNS topic can **DependsOn** EC2 instance. This ensures that by that time SNS creation is triggered, your service is healthy.